# What happen exactly Dispatcher.IO + job when define CoroutineScope?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I use `Coroutine` in my project and defined a class as `CoroutineScope` for handling `Coroutines` on difference `Dispatchers` such as `IO`, `MAIN` ...
but I do not understand that this code how work and what is mechanism it?

```
val job = Job()

override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
     get() = Dispatchers.IO + job
```

what's mean `Dispatchers.IO + job` ?

Comment: It's a `CoroutineContext` that consists of two elements: the dispatcher and the job. The  type `CoroutineContext` is also itself a `ContextElement`, and you can combine `ContextElement`s with `+`.

Comment: When would we use `Dispatchers.Main`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The advantage of using an specified job with Dispatchers.IO is that you can cancel that job any time without effecting other jobs that launched in the IO Dispatcher.
You simply can call `job.cancel()`

for example you make a network request and while it's running somehow you find out network is down (for example from a BroadCastReciever if in android), then you can cancel that network job.
but remember you always have to make a new Job if job is cancelled or completed